# How to get URL without 2%e %23... etc

Tags: joomla

I've created a form for search results:

```
<form id="searchForm" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_new');?>" method="get">

<fieldset class="word">
    <label for="search-searchword">
        <?php echo Word; ?>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_new');?>searchword" id="search-searchword" size="30" value="<?php echo $this->escape($this->origkeyword); ?>" class="inputbox" />


    <button name="Search" onclick="this.form.submit()" class="button"><?php echo Submit;?></button>
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="search" />

</fieldset>
```

the url I get is:

```
/index.php?%2Fsearch%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_newsearchword=&Search=&task=search
```

Comment: search for url decode in the internets.

Comment: Btw any other suggestions for a different form is welcome, I took this form from com_search view.

Comment: I gave you some clarification about url and url parameters. But I have the feeling this is not quite what you are targetting at. You may want to clearifiy what you really want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL consists of several parts, like subdomain, domain, path, url parameters. For all these parts you have certain rules. One rule says: you may not have certain characters in a URL parameters. Especially not characters that are used to describe the parameters itself like:

- ? which is used to mark the start of the url parameter section
- & which is used to mark the start of any additional url parameter
- = which is used to mark the start of the value of an url parameter.

So these characters have to be encoded. And that is what you see. If you need to get the first (unnamed) url parameter and then decode that.

This might be of some help:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php